# Python regular expressions: disallowing characters with exceptions

Tags: python, regex

In my actual project I want to get some input from a user. It cannot contain whitespace at the beginning, at the end or twice or more in a row and it also cannot contain anything that is not a letter or a number.

However I have 2 problems:

1. `\W` disallows whitespaces. I want to allow one but not in the beginning, the end or more than once.
2. I want to allow dots but `\W` disallows it. I can't replace it with `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\s.]` because it disallows characters like 'äöüß' which I want to allow. How can I change my code to disallow everything that is in the pattern below except for single whitespaces and dots?

```
input_text = input("input: ")
if re.search(r"(^\s|\s{2,}|\s$|\W)", input_text)
    print("invalid input")
```

Comment: You need ``^[^\W_]+(?:[\s.][^\W_]+)*\Z``, don't you? `if re.search(r'^[^\W_]+(?:[\s.][^\W_]+)*\Z', input_text): print('Valid')`

Comment: See [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/ROB6Il/1). Can a dot appear at the end/start? Can there be two consecutive dots? If there can be dots anywhere, use `^(?:[^\W_]|\.)+(?:\s(?:[^\W_]|\.)+)*\Z`. See [demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/ROB6Il/2).

Comment: You can always quickly try regex solutions on https://regex101.com. I find it very useful in narrowing down to what I need and then ask questions if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use either of the two:

```py
^[^\W_]+(?:[\s.][^\W_]+)*\Z
^(?:[^\W_]|\.)+(?:\s(?:[^\W_]|\.)+)*\Z
```

The first one will match single dots and whitespace only in between letters. The second one allows dots to be anywhere in the string and in any consecutive quantities.
See [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ROB6Il/1) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/ROB6Il/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\W_]+` - one or more Unicode letters or digits
- `(?:[^\W_]|\.)+` - a non-capturing group matching one or more Unicode letters/digits or a dot
- `(?:[\s.][^\W_]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `[\s.]` -  a single whitespace or dot
  - `[^\W_]+` - one or more Unicode letters or digits
- `\Z` - the very end of string.

In Python, use something like

```py
if re.search(r'^[^\W_]+(?:[\s.][^\W_]+)*\Z', input_text):
  print('Valid')
```